# Meu dropdown não importa opções do banco

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, dropdown

Tenho um formulário com um `dropdown`, que deveria ter como opções os usuários cadastrados em uma tabela do meu banco de dados.

**A conexão:**

```
 <?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_formacao");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

**O formulário:**

```
    <!-- Content -->
<?php 
    require 'conn.php';
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT NOME FROM colaboradores");
?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1 style="
                    margin-top:100px;">Inscrição</h1>
                <p> </p>
                <p class="lead"></p>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <form id="cadastro" method="post" action="banco/updateP.php" style="
                        text-align: left;
                        margin-top:50px;">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" style="
                        text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="FORMACAO">Formação: </label>
                                <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="FORMACAO" name="FORMACAO" value="<?=$row['nome']?>">
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                        text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="TURMA">Turma: </label>
                                <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="TURMA" name="TURMA">
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                        text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="COLABORADOR">Colaborador: </label>
                                <select  class="form-control" id="COLABORADOR" name="COLABORADOR">
                                <option>Selecione...</option>
                                <?php while($colab = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $colab['NOME']; ?>"><?php echo $colab['NOME']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                        text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="PREVISTO">Status: </label>
                                <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="PREVISTO" name="PREVISTO" value="Previsto">
                             </div>
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline disabled">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="STATUS" id="STATUS" value="Realizado" disabled> Realizado
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Simplesmente não aparecem as opções. Alguém pode me apontar onde está o erro?

Comment: Olá @MarianaFerreira. Primeiramente, você está utilizando uma extensão que foi *descontinuada* - **mysql***.

Comment: Segundo ponto, como está modelada a tabela **colaboradores**? Ela possui uma coluna em *capslock* chamada **NOME**?

Comment: A variável que deveria imprimir seria a $prod e não a $colab (que aparentemente não existe)

Comment: Obrigada por responder, Godfrey! Primeiro ponto: Eu uso uma versão antiga do php e não posso atualizar, então o Mysqli não funciona tão bem pra mim.  Segundo ponto: Sim, minha tabela possui uma coluna em caps chamada NOME.  Terceiro ponto: alterei a variável do while para $colab, mas ainda assim não funciona.

Comment: @MarianaFerreira Publiquei uma resposta antes de verificar esse seu último comentário. Aconselho seriamente em você, se possível atualizar para *mysqli*. Caso seja impossível, em minha resposta, utilize a extensão *mysql**.

Comment: @MarianaFerreira Me diga uma coisa... Você comentou que a extensão *mysqli* não funciona tão bem para você... Mas ela está disponível a partir da versã 5 para cima do PHP. Qual versão você está utilizando? Realmente não há nenhum sentindo em vc utilizar a extensão *mysql**.

Comment: Eu utilizo a versão 5.2.10. É impossível atualizar porque muitos sistemas rodam nessa versão e boa parte eu nem tenho acesso.

Comment: Vou tentar usar o mysqli

Comment: Essa aplicação está em ambiente de produção? Se estiver, então utilize *mysql** mesmo. Se estiver em produção e a extensão não funcionar, talvez você deverá compilar o *PHP* com uma flag indicando o *mysqli*... Portanto, repito, se estiver em produção continue com a *mysql*.

Comment: Mari, dá uma olhada na minha edição. Apenas substitua seu select por aquele que coloquei.

Comment: Se vc está usando o código acima como ele está publicado, vc empastelou mysqli_ com mysql. Vela $connection = mysqli_connect.... E no formulario  while($colab = mysql_fetch_array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
    require 'conn.php';
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT NOME FROM colaboradores");
?>

   ...
   ...

                        <select  class="form-control" id="COLABORADOR" name="COLABORADOR">
                            <option>Selecione...</option>
                            <?php while($colab = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $colab['NOME']; ?>"><?php echo $colab['NOME']; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>

                        </select>
```

---

**Se caso tenha interesse em utilizar Mysqli**:

Faça as seguintes modificações em seu arquivo `conn.php`:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_formacao");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

Agora em seu outro arquivo, onde está o `HTML`:

---

E posteriormente em seu código:

```
 <?php 
    while ($prod = $query->fetch_array()) {
     echo '<option value="' . $prod['NOME'] . '">' . $prod['NOME'] . '</option>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Então, segui suas recomendações, mas aconteceu algo muito estranho. Depois de usar seu código, toda a página depois do dropdown simplesmente sumiu. Vou editar com uma foto.

Comment: A página voltou a aparecer! Mas ainda não está importando as opções do banco. :/

Comment: Sabe o trecho `mysql_fetch_array($query)`? Comente aquele `while` e no lugar escreva `var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($query));` para debugarmos o seu código.

Comment: Outra coisa... Você está utilizando agora *mysqli* ou *mysql*? Pra eu editar minha resposta.

Comment: Estou usando mysqli

Comment: Ok, vou editar minha resposta e deixar somente o *mysqli*. Você debugou o código como solicitei?

Comment: Sim, mas não deu certo, então, voltei para o while

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64541/discussion-between-godfrey-the-king-and-mariana-ferreira).

Answer (score 1):

Vc não incluiu os nomes nas `<option>`. O Correto seria:

```
<option value="<?php echo $colab['NOME'] ?>"><?php echo $colab['NOME'] ?></option>
```

Geralmente atribui-se um "id" vindo do banco para cada `value` das `<option>`, tipo:

```
<option value="<?php echo $colab['id'] ?>"><?php echo $colab['NOME'] ?></option>
```

Mas também é preciso selecionar na query essa "id":

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ID, NOME FROM pacientes");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Correções feitas utilizando MySQL_i:**

1. `$query = ("SELECT NOME FROM colaboradores");`
2. `$results = mysqli_query($connection,$query);`
3. `<?php while($colab = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>`

**O formulário corrigido:**

```
<?php
 require 'conn.php';

    $query = ("SELECT NOME FROM colaboradores");
    $results = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
?>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1 style="
                margin-top:100px;">Inscrição</h1>
            <p> </p>
            <p class="lead"></p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <form id="cadastro" method="post" action="banco/updateP.php" style="
                    text-align: left;
                    margin-top:50px;">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="FORMACAO">Formação: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="FORMACAO" name="FORMACAO" value="<?=$row['nome']?>">
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="TURMA">Turma: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="TURMA" name="TURMA">
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="COLABORADOR">Colaborador: </label>
                            <select  class="form-control" id="COLABORADOR" name="COLABORADOR">
                            <option>Selecione....</option>
                            <?php while($colab = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $colab['NOME']; ?>"><?php echo $colab['NOME']; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="PREVISTO">Status: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="PREVISTO" name="PREVISTO" value="Previsto">
                         </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline disabled">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="STATUS" id="STATUS" value="Realizado" disabled> Realizado
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**A conexão:**

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "db_formacao");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```